# Async call not working when calling service - Angular 8

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, httpclient, angular7

Synchronicity does not work in the call to an API service with httpClient, post method and does not wait for the return of the response

Component.ts

```js
this.juiciosService.createJuicio(this.juicio).then(
    (res: any) => {
      if(res.ok == 200){
        Swal.fire({
          //position: 'top-end',
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'Cedula agregada con exito',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 2000
        })
        this.detalleJuicio(res.data)
      }
      else {
        Swal.fire({
          //position: 'top-end',
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'No se pudo agregar la cedula',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 2000
        })
      }
      this.spinnerService.hide();
    }
  )
```

service.ts

```js
  async createJuicio(juicio): Promise<Juicio> {
    console.log(juicio);
    const url = this.API_URL + 'juicios/Crearjuicios/';
    return await this.http
      .post<Juicio>(url, juicio).toPromise()
      .then(res => res)
  }
```

Comment: Since you are using Promise#then callback, you dont need async/await at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to this:

```
async methodName()
{
  let res = await this.juiciosService.createJuicio(this.juicio);
  if(res.ok == 200){
     Swal.fire({
          //position: 'top-end',
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'Cedula agregada con exito',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 2000
     });
     this.detalleJuicio(res.data)
  }
  else{
   
   Swal.fire({
          //position: 'top-end',
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'No se pudo agregar la cedula',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 2000
        })
    
  }
}
```

This way it would works as an async function.

Also, Don't forget to do exception handling on one of the functions. Since seems that if your HTTP Call fails, the Spinner will not hide.